# Rock Mongo mongodb config settings

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I have installed **RockMongo** http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/ to manage my **mongoDB** database. This is installed in a subdirectory of my site http://mongo.example.com. The default config settings are as follows:

> "host" => "192.168.1.1", // Replace your MongoDB host ip or domain name here
>   "port" => "27017", // MongoDB connection port
>   "username" => null, // MongoDB connection username
>   "password" => null, // MongoDB connection password

I'm not really sure what I should be changing these to? On log in all I get is:

> MongoDB connection exception: connecting to mongodb://192.168.1.1:27017 failed: Operation now in progress. Please check your configuration.

Comment: Did you make sure mongodb is running?

Comment: Yep and I can connect through the shell to a test database

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831939/couldnt-connect-to-server-127-0-0-127017#17793856

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working:

1. Reinstalled mongodb properly
2. Cleared browser cache
3. Restarted server
4. Set host to 'localhost'

Answer (score 35):

This is what I see from the [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/rock_mongo#Quick_Install)

> Login with admin username and
>   password, which is set "admin" and
>   "admin" as default

Comment: Yep I'm trying to login with user/password admin:admin, which is definately correct and set elsewhere in the config file. The section I've highlighted above I believe is the mongodb username and password - which I don't think exist unless they have been set explicitly (which I haven't done) - so I think those two fields are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set below configuration in config.php file

```
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_auth"] = false;

$MONGO["servers"][$i]["control_auth"] = false;
```