# MongoDB stops when I try to make a connection

Tags: mongodb

Mongodb stops whenever I try to make a connection.

When I run

```
sudo service mongod start
```

I get a message that mongodb is running.

But then when I try to make a connection using PyMongo I get an error that says

```
Autoreconnect: connection closed
```

I check my mongodb status:

```
sudo service mongod status
```

And it says that my mongodb instance is stopped/waiting.

My mongo log file reports the following:

```
2015-09-17T18:19:46.816+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for     connections on port 7000
2015-09-17T18:19:58.813+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection     accepted from 54.152.111.120:51387 #1 (1 connection now open)
2015-09-17T18:19:58.816+0000 I STORAGE  [conn1] _getOpenFile() invalid file index requested 4
2015-09-17T18:19:58.816+0000 I -        [conn1] Invariant failure false src/mongo/db/storage/mmap_v1/mmap_v1_extent_manager.cpp 201
2015-09-17T18:19:58.837+0000 I CONTROL  [conn1]
```

This is followed by a lengthy backtrace that I can't decipher, then closes with:

```
2015-09-17T18:19:58.837+0000 I -        [conn1]

 ***aborting after invariant() failure
```

I've looked around SO, particularly trying the top two answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831939/couldnt-connect-to-server-127-0-0-127017), but haven't been able to figure out how to solve the problem.

I'll also note that last time I tried to connect last week, it was working fine.

Comment: Not enough log lines to get a conclution.
Usually what you describe points to file system problems (corrupted data files, not enough storage, file access permisions etc)
Try to log into mongo shell and do a db.stats() see if it works, and if yes may be you will get more insight of what happens.

Comment: Thanks! When I try to log into a shell, mongo stops, just as if I were trying to make a remote connection.

Comment: May be change the data directory in mongo config file then restart mongo to check if that works. If yes you can try recovering the data with mongo restore