# Why MongoDB is only connecting to: test schema?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

Installed mongodb 3.2.16 on ubuntu 16.04 and configured to start automatically but left connection hanging when issuing `mongo` from the terminal. Previous access works fine.

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.16
connecting to: test
```

Accessing `http://localhost:27017` works fine. Also checked if `mongod` is running using `top` and it's there.

Answer (score 0):

My question has been solved here. I did not encounter any error message but tried my luck and it works.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/34835813/1638149