# Not Able to Connect MongoDB server in Manjaro, Error with exit code 100

Tags: linux, mongodb, mongoose, terminal, manjaro

I installed Mongodb From AUR Pacman, I tried reinstalling the Mongo but it didn't work, I also tried Arch Troubleshooting methods but it didn't work either.

I get following when I try **sudo mongod**

```html
[omr@auckwell ~]$ sudo mongo
[sudo] password for omr: 
[omr@auckwell ~]$ sudo mongod
[sudo] password for omr: 
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.531+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.540+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.541+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.542+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":18541,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"auckwell"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.542+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.1","gitVersion":"ad91a93a5a31e175f5cbf8c69561e788bbc55ce1","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu1804","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.542+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"ManjaroLinux","version":"20.1.1"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.542+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.544+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.544+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":10000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.544+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.544+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.544+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.544+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.544+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.544+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.544+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.544+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.544+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.544+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.544+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.544+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.544+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.544+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-25T12:26:27.544+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}
[omr@auckwell ~]$
```

```html
[omr@auckwell ~]$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
[omr@auckwell ~]$
```

and above result while trying mongo only!

Answer (score 8):

Your issue possibly occurs due to the mongod process is down, you must run the commands bellow in order to get the mongod process up:

```
~$ sudo service mongodb stop

~$ sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock

~$ sudo mongod --repair --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb

~$ sudo mongod --fork --logpath /var/lib/mongodb/mongodb.log --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb

~$ sudo service mongodb start
```

Comment: @Om Raval your question is dublicate. cant mark it due to insufficent reputation. there is already an answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831939/couldnt-connect-to-server-127-0-0-127017)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a folder `/data/db`

That's what it says in the terminal {"error":"Nonexistent path: data directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory

You can do this with the command `sudo mkdir -p /data/db`

Answer (score -2):

Just create a folder inside C:\data\db .      My same problem was solved by doing this.

Comment: that is a windows file structure. the owner of the question states that he is on manjaro