# mongodb-org-4.0.repo : No such file or directory al instalar el mongo shell en mi AWS Cloud9

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, pymongo, c9.io

I try to connect to the mion cluster DocumentDB on AWS from AWS C9 with [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ild9ay9U_vY). But every time I try to connect I get connection failed after 6 attempts:

```
(scr_env) me:~/environment/sephora $ mongo --ssl --host xxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxx --sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --username username --password mypassword
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://xxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxx/
2022-03-22T23:12:38.725+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2022-03-22T23:12:38.726+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server xxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxx, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Indeed it seems to be missing the VPC configuration. So I tried to do with [this documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17793856/4764604). But I do not know how to install the mongo shell on my AWS Cloud9. Indeed, it seems that I cannot create the repository file with the `echo -e "[mongodb-org-4.0] \name=MongoDB repository baseurl=...`.
returns: `mongodb-org-4.0.repo: No such file or directory`.

Also, when I tried to install the mongo shell with `sudo yum install -y mongodb-org-shell` which I did not have, and which I installed, it returns `repolist 0`.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used DocumentDB on AWS, but what I answer here is a general solution to most of the failing connection issues:

The "fail to connect" error can be caused by a lot of reasons, but usually they are:

- the service (mongo) might not be *running* on the destination server;
- the service (mongo) might be *listening* on a different port number;
- the service (mongo) might be *protected* by a firewall somewhere on the destination.

So you might want to ensure that:

- mongo is *running* on the destination host;
- mongo is *listening* on the defined port;
- you're *allowed* to connect to the destination host on the defined port from the IP address or network range you're running the command to connect.

Comment: Hi Nilton ! Thanks for your answer! Actually the error seems to be that Cloud9 instance is in the same VPC as Amazon DocumentDB cluster